# Condense data to put all data on ID row

Tags: excel, data-modeling

I am trying to condense data in a table in Excel using some kind of manage data. Otherwise I could try to use VBA.
The data table has an ID column, a column indicating sub-tables, and the remaining columns are filled depending on whether that data comes from that sub table.
I don't care about the sub-tables, I just want all the data on the same row.
There are always the same number of subTables, and subTables always have data in the same columns.

Original:
[Original_Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNasg.png)

Would like:
[Final_Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17MNz.png)

Comment: Please provide sample data in table format. Please show what you already tried.

Comment: What have you tried?  And where have you run into problems?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution, that while not elegant works.
I deleted the subtable column (Object Name), then I "Unpivoted the data", which removed the null values, and left me with a table of ID #s (Tracking ID) attributes and values.

let
Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Tracking #", type text}, {"Object Name", type text}, ... blah blah ... type any}}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Object Name"}),
#"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"Tracking #"}, "Attribute", "Value")
in
#"Unpivoted Columns"

Then back in Excel I copied a unique column of IDs and unique headings of attributes and did a match and lookup.

=INDEX(Table1_2[Value],MATCH($G2&H$1,Table1_2[Column1],0))

(Column 1 is a concat of ID # & attributes; G2 = ID # and H1 = attribute.)